# Station Passage for an NDB

Tags: holding, ndb

I read somewhere that the first station passage for an NDB holding pattern is when the bearing pointer passes the 90 degree index. Then the document went on to say that for subsequent crossing of the holding fix, station passage was when the bearing pointer passed the 45 degree index. Why? Is this just a technique, if not, what is the reason?

I read this in the appendix to an Air Force manual.

Comment: References are always good ...

Comment: If you're decently aligned overhead when crossing the beacon, it flips around fairly quickly anyway. It's probably a way to anticipate and lead the turn a bit to fly a tighter pattern, but I don't think it makes much difference and you have plenty of protected airspace around you.

Comment: Do you know where your read this?

Comment: I had no idea people were still flying NDB holding patterns. Was the music that good? :)

Comment: @JuanJimenez In the U.S. there are almost 190 NDB approaches. Likely many have associated NDB holding (e.g. IAF, MAP holding, etc.). They are still around.